# Move back. You will spill yourself

Tags: grammar

I was frying a fish in the kitchen.

He was standing close to the stove.

> "Move back. You will burn yourself."
>
> "Move back. You will spill yourself."
>
> "Move back. You will get spilled."

When an oil spills on hand, can I use "burn"?

Comment: If you are not a semi-liquid jelly beast from the planet Kraal, you are not likely to be spilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Spill" isn't really the verb you want to use.  Instead you want to warn him against being *splashed* or *burned*.

> Watch out, you'll get **splashed** by hot oil.
>
> Watch out, you'll get **burned** by hot oil.

It's also incorrect to use the reflexive pronoun *yourself* since he isn't the one who is doing the cooking.  You are.

It would be different if he was going to touch the hot stove with his hands:

> Watch out, don't touch the stove.  It's hot and you'll **burn yourself**.

You can also use the very specific verb *spatter* which means "to cover with drops or spots of something, usually fluid" and which is often used to describe the pattern of oil drops from a hot skillet.

> Keep away from the stove or you might get **spattered** by the hot oil.

This is why it's a good idea to use a [*spatter guard*](http://a.co/2CCDI6E) when frying.

Comment: *Spilling* generally can only happen to things that can also be *poured.*